# Do I keep my Windows installation if I install Ubuntu with Wubi, the Windows installer?

Tags: installation, windows, wubi

I want to know if I will keep and still be able to use my Windows 7 installation after I use the Wubi Windows Installer (from [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/help/install-ubuntu-with-windows)) to install Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance,
Bas.

Comment: In fact, if you uses the Windows installer, you have to keep Windows.

Comment: Please select an answer as the solution to mark this thread as solved.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, WUBI installs Ubuntu inside the Windows filesystem and just changes the Windows bootloader.

Most people consider a WUBI install to be slower than a proper install (where the Windows partition is removed or resized) because it has to rely on the Windows filesystem to work. If you get on well with a WUBI install, you might want to consider a proper dual-boot install.

Answer (score 4):

Your windows 7 installation will remain untouched.

When you boot your computer you'll be able to choose which operating system you want to boot into (as shown in the last screenshot in the link you sent).

Comment: Technically this is not true, as it will re-size the size of your disk, and will also install GRUB over top the MBR. But you will still be able to use Windows as you did before, minus some disc space.

Comment: @TheX No, that's not how WUBI works.

Comment: oh yeah... I always forget about Wubi.... little slow this morning I guess lol

Comment: Please considering editing your answer to correct the problems pointed out in the other comments. This is friendlier than requiring someone to read every comment to get an accurate answer.

Comment: The first time you reboot after installing Wubi in Windows 7 it will boot straight to Ubuntu (with no prompt). Thereafter, the Windows Boot Manager gives you the choice of which operating system to boot.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you will keep your windows installation. Wubi installs Ubuntu inside the windows filesystem. The only thing it does is changing your boot sector. You will have to choose which system to boot each time you start your PC.

Comment: Wubi doesn't change the contents of the boot sector. It does edit the configuration for the Windows boot menu, but that configuration is not stored in the MBR.